# react native ImageBackground not using full width

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I have a Screen:

```
return (

    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <ImageBackground source={require('../../../../assets/start.png')} resizeMode="cover" style={styles.image}>
            <Text>Some Text</Text>
        </ImageBackground>
    </SafeAreaView>
);
```

And these are the styles I'm using:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  image: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
```

})

The problem is my background Image has white space around it.

[image]

From the above image you can see that the image has a gap at the top and the left side, it also has the same gap on the bottom and right.

Im trying to get this image edge to edge. Any idea?

iv tried adding 100% width and height and applying resize properties to the image, but its not working?

Comment: The image itself doesn't have the white edges but it is rendered with those, correct? Have you checked the [browser devtools to see what causes the artifact](https://www.turnwall.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/basics-07-devtools-1024x627.png)? Is the parent element of `<SafeAreaView />` also a flex container? If so, the `flex: 1` might make it extend to the full parent width.

Comment: yes, the image doesn't have the edges, but its rendered with white edges. adding flex 1 or removing it, hasn't helped with the fix :(

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the full JSX markups. Wondering if the white edges occurs between `<SafeAreaView />`  and `<ImageBackground />` or between `<SafeAreaView />` and its parent.